# Couldn't able to read the attribute using DOM parser

Tags: java

i am having issues when reading the attribute of a link,

this is the structure of my xml,

```
    <entry>
        <updated>
        <title>
        <link href="">
    </entry>
```

i managed to read the date and title correctly but the `href` attribute of the `link` is not working.

Here is my code,

```
NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("entry");
            System.out.println("============================");

            for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++)
            {
             Node node = nList.item(temp);
             System.out.println("");    //Just a separator
             if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
             {
                Element eElement = (Element) node;
                System.out.println("Date : "  + eElement.getElementsByTagName("updated").item(0).getTextContent());
                System.out.println("Title : "    + eElement.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).getTextContent());

                // The below code is for reading href attribute of link,
                NodeList node1 = eElement.getElementsByTagName("link");
                Element eElement1 = (Element) node1;
                System.out.println(eElement1.getAttribute("href"));

             }
            }
```

I am creating a new nodelist for the attributes of link but the code is not working.

error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeepNodeListImpl cannot be cast to org.w3c.dom.Element
    at Demo.main(Demo.java:45)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `NodeList` is not an `Element` and cannot be cast to one (successfully), so this code isn't going to work:

```
NodeList node1 = eElement.getElementsByTagName("link");
Element eElement1 = (Element) node1;
```

A `NodeList` is, as the name suggests, a **list** of nodes (and in your case, the nodes will be `Element`s). So this code would work for the first `link`:

```
NodeList list = eElement.getElementsByTagName("link");
Element eElement1 = (Element) list.item(0);
```

...whereupon your `getAttribute` should work fine, as `Element` has `getAttribute`.

---

Side note: If your library has support for newer query functions, you could also do this:

```
String href = ((Element)eElement.querySelector("entry")).getAttribute("href");
```

...because `querySelector` returns just the first match (not a list) (or `null` if no matches; if that's a possibility, add a guard to the above). But I don't know how well `querySelector` is supported outside of browsers yet.

Comment: how `item(0)` get the link of every link element ? shouldn't it return the link of link with index 0?

Comment: @Joe: `getElementsByTagName` returns a *list* of all matches; even if there's just one match, it returns a *list* containing one entry. To get the first thing in the list, you use `.item(0)` (and the second thing would be `.item(1)`, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

```
  // The below code is for reading href attribute of link,
 NodeList node1 = eElement.getElementsByTagName("link");
 Element eElement1 = (Element) node1;
```

`NodeList` will give you `Node` object not `Element`, you can get href value as follows,

```
String hrefValue = nodeList.item(0).
       getAttributes().getNamedItem("href").getNodeValue();
```

Comment: why item(0) get the link of each item, shouldn't it just return the link of them item with index 0 ?

Comment: It will return `0th` index item in your NodeList, NodeList is a list of elements you can access any element from this list by giving index.